# How does shareit discovers nearby devices android programmatically

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, wifi

I'm want to create a file sharing app like shareit but I'm really confused about how shareit discovers the nearby devices.

When you click receive button shareit creates a hotspot at the receiver side and the sender without connecting to the hotspot shows the receiver name. How is that possible?

If shareit uses Wi-Fi direct then what's the point of creating hotspot?

And to use Network Service Discovery (NSD) both server and client should be on same network so I think shareit is using something else

If anyone can explain this concept of shareit it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the answer! SHAREit uses WiFi SSID to identify the nearby app users.
The SSID Consist of two partslike this. BAHD-bXViYQ WHERE 'B' Stands for ANDROID DEVICE and the AHD for the user icon. the second part is the user name encoded in Base64. In this example my name muba.
I hope this answer helps save some time.

Comment: @Mubark Ali How other device able to scan created network ?

Comment: Either they use a common port or they have a custom host discovery protocol. Those are trivial by the way.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 could you please point out some examples to achieve something like that?

Comment: @PhaniRithvij On W/LAN, A simple broadcast/multicast packet can let you do that. Here's an example: https://michieldemey.be/blog/network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast/ But you'd want to use a library instead of that code, unless you know what you're doing

Comment: @AndroidDeveloperWorld You have to scan for wifi ssids and decrypt using Base64decode. sorry for delayed reply.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have found how to enable the `hotspot` from one sharing app and find the list of available wifi enabled by that sharing app into another one. just like shareIt `receiver` enables the wifi hotspot and `sender discovers` the list of available `receivers`. 
First of all You have to scan all available wifi network using `WifiManager`

```
public void startScan(){
    mWifiManager.startScan();
    mScanResultList = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
    mWifiConfigurations = mWifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
}
```

now pass this `mScanResultList` to a method which finds the network according to your requirement.

```
public static List<ScanResult> filterWithNoPassword(List<ScanResult> scanResultList){
    if(scanResultList == null || scanResultList.size() == 0){
        return scanResultList;
    }

    List<ScanResult> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(ScanResult scanResult : scanResultList){
        if(scanResult.capabilities != null && scanResult.capabilities.equals(NO_PASSWORD) || scanResult.capabilities != null && scanResult.capabilities.equals(NO_PASSWORD_WPS)){
            resultList.add(scanResult);
        }
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

Now pass the `resultList` to arraylist adapter to show the network in list. Inside adapter's `convertView` method just pass that dataList to scanner to get ssid and mac address of the network

```
@Override
public View convertView(int position, View convertView) {
    ScanResultHolder viewHolder = null;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.item_wifi_scan_result, null);
        viewHolder = new ScanResultHolder();
        viewHolder.iv_device = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_device);
        viewHolder.tv_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        viewHolder.tv_mac = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_mac);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ScanResultHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ScanResult scanResult = getDataList().get(position);
    if(scanResult != null){
        viewHolder.tv_name.setText(scanResult.SSID);
        viewHolder.tv_mac.setText(scanResult.BSSID);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

This is the code to enable the `hotspot`

```
public static boolean configApState(Context context, String apName) {
    WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiConfiguration wificonfiguration = null;
    try {
        wificonfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
        wificonfiguration.SSID = apName;
        // if WiFi is on, turn it off
        if(isApOn(context)) {
            wifimanager.setWifiEnabled(false);
            // if ap is on and then disable ap
            disableAp(context);
        }
        Method method = wifimanager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
        method.invoke(wifimanager, wificonfiguration, !isApOn(context));
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```